# Keep drop down open when mouse is over menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys I'm kind of stuck with i'm such a very easy solution. However, it's been doing my head in so I though i'd see if someone else can take the pressure of my brain haha. Anyway, I've created a drop down with a on hover event to make it appear. So when the mouse is over the button the drop down appears. Now the issue i'm having is that I also want it to stay on screen when the mouse is over the menu.

```js
$("#ddBtn").hover(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ddBtn {
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.pageBtns {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
}

#page {
  border: 2px solid #999;
}

#dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button id="ddBtn" class="ddBtn">Drop Down</button>

  <div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
    <button class="pageBtns">Page1</button>
    <button class="pageBtns">Page2</button>
    <button class="pageBtns">Page3</button>
    <button class="pageBtns">Page4</button>
    <button class="pageBtns">Page5</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your button styles aren't done. The parent button `ddBtn` is the one with the hover rule applied and when you move the mouse outside of the button, the menu disappears as expected. You may want to move the sub menu items closer to the parent so there is no gap between `ddBtn` and your first `pageBtns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it without jquery:

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding:10px 0;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now.
    My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated
    decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater.
    Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game
    gate west face shed. &#65279;no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It may help to explain to the OP why this behavior is happening in the event that they don't like your style choices and try to change them and get the error again.